# Using "(?=<)" in regex leads to "E866: (NFA regexp) Misplaced ?"

Tags: regular-expression

The following command should output the string "`st`":

```
:echo matchstr('test', '\(\?<=e\).*')
```

However, it leads to the error mentioned in the title. Reading `:h E866` didn't help much. I also tried changing the escapes in the expression (i.e. `\(?<=e\).*`, `\(\?\<=e\).*`, `\(?\<=e\).*`, etc...), but to no avail.

What's wrong with my usage of `?<=`, and how may I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?<=pattern)` is from the perl regex dialect.  In vim, this concept is spelled `\%(pattern\)\@<=`.  So a full working example would be:

```
echo matchstr('test', '\(\%(e\)\@<=\).*')
" prints st
```

In the case where the pattern that precedes `\@<=` is a single atom, the inner `\%()` group can be omitted.  For example,

```
echo matchstr('test', '\(e\@<=\).*')
```